# How do I get IE 10 to show a pointer instead of an I-bar for a select list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list that user can select from. cursor: pointer shows a hand or pointer except in IE 10 which shows an I-bar. How can I get IE 10 to show a pointer rather than an I-bar? I've tried all the suggestions I've found here for questions about showing a hand or pointer and none of them worked.

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS code that produces the phenomenon. By default, IE 10 uses an arrow pointer when a `select` element is moused over. So if you see an l-bar, something special is going on.

Comment: Here is the CSS code: .sugg_box {
 display: none;
 width: 550px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-size: 11pt;
 background-color: #466991;
 border: 2px solid gray;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
Here is the HTML code: <ul id='cityfromsuggestbox' class='sugg_box'> and the php which generates the li lines:  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  echo "<li id='sugg_search' onclick='javascript:putAirlineSuggestion(this);'>".$row['airline_name']."</li>";
The onclick works even though the cursor is an I-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers use different names.

`{cursor: hand;
     cursor: pointer; 
    }`

Will cover you in all cases.

Comment: Use `cursor:pointer` only. `cursor:hand` is only required if you need to support IE5.5 or earlier. Everything else supports `cursor:pointer`.

Comment: Why do you have `display: none;` in the .sugg_box class?

Comment: Also, check whether the list in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/enecid/4) works in IE 10 for you.